# Help with absolute value proof.

Tags: proof-verification, absolute-value

Please help me with the following proof:

Show that if $|x-1|<1$ and $|x-1|<r/4$, where $r \in \Bbb R^+$, then $|x^2+x-2|<r$.

This is the solution that is in my textbook:

First, observe that 
$$|x^2+x-2|=|(x+2)(x-1)|=|x+2||x-1|.$$

By Theorem 4.17,
$$|x+2|=|(x-1)+3|\leq|x-1|+|3|<1+3=4.$$

Therefore,
$$|x^2+x-2|=|x+2||x-1|<4(r/4)=r.$$

For reference, Theorem 4.17 is the following:
For every real numbers $x$ and $y$, $|x+y|\leq|x|+|y|.$

I understand everything but the second half of the second part of the proof. Where does $1+3$ come from and how is it related to $|x-1|+|3|$?

Thanks.

Comment: It is given that $|x-1|<1$, and clearly $|3|=3$, hence $|x-1|+|3|<1+3$. What are you confused about?

Comment: @Math1000 that makes sense. I'm (obviously) pretty new to proofs and have difficulty in recognizing when to use information I've been given. In the third line of the proof, how is it established that |x+2||x−1|<4(r/4)? I understand that |x+2|<4 and |x-1|<1, but surely it isn't always the case that if x<y and m<n, then xm<yn?

Comment: In the preceeding line we established that $|x+2|<4$, and it was given that $|x-1|<r/4$. Hence, $|x+2||x-1|<4(r/4)$.

Comment: Be careful about multiplying inequalities. They do not always remain true when one or both sides are negative. For example, $1<2$ and $-2<-1$, but we do not have $-2<-2$.

Comment: Ah, but because |x+2| and |x-1| are both positive regardless of what x+2 and x-1 equal, it is proper in this case.

Answer (score 1):

$2 = -1 + 3$  I hope that is obvious.

We did this because we know something about $x-1$

This one:

$|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$ is called the triangle inequality.

You can't make a triangle if the two shorter sides are  not at least as long as the longest side.  Or, the shortest distance between two points is a straight line.

You probably should prove this to yourself.  The most direct way to prove such a thing would be to create 4 cases.

Both a,b are positive.
a is positive and b is negative
a is negative and b is positive
both are negative.

A more elegant proof would be to square both sides.